# llamar una funcion dentro de otra python

Tags: python

Hola estoy intentando crear un programa que lea un lista y me muestre todos sus elementos luego que elimine el primero y el ultimo. Y que la lista final la que quedo sin el primer y ultimo elemento sea llamado a otra lista (medio) y luego eliminar el primer y ultimo elemento de esa lista, pero no se como llamar la lista de una función a otra

```
def elimina():

    lista = ["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo"]
    print(lista[0:7])

    lista.pop(0)
    lista.pop(5)

    return lista[0:5]

def medio():

print(elimina())
```

Comment: simplemente dentro de `elimina` haz la llamada `medio()` y tienes 2 opciones la primera sería pasar la lista por parámetro y la segundo declarar la lista como global. Lo tuyo huele más a recursión. Podrías explicar mejor el problema? tal vez estas pensando mal la solución.

Comment: El problema es asi tengo que escribir los elementos de una lista ejemplo lista= [1,2,3,4,5] luego se tienen que eliminar el primer y ultimo elemento de la lista quedaría lista = [2,3,4] eso tiene que ir en la primera función se llama eliminar, luego tengo que crear otra función que se llame medio el cual tiene que eliminar el primer y ultimo elemento de nuevo de la lista entonces la lista quedaría lista = [3], pero no se como pasar la lista a la otra función

Comment: tienes que tener obligatoriamente otro método? No sería mejor tener una función recursiva? O solo quieres hacerlo una vez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realiza lo siguiente:

1. pon primero la `def medio()` con su lógica que reciba una lista.
2. Llama a medio(), desde la segunda función.

Algo como:

```
def medio(listaRecibida):
   #logica faltante
   print(listaRecibida)


def elimina():

    listaActual = ["Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo"]
    print(listaActual[0:7])

    listaActual.pop(0)
    listaActual.pop(5)

    medio(listaActual)


elimina()
```

Porque se pone la función `medio(lista)` antes de la función `elimina()`.
Resulta que el compilador va linea a linea y resulta que debes tener compilada la función para poder utilizarla, entonces tienes que definir todas las funciones que quieras, antes de la función principal de tu sistema.

Comment: El problema es así tengo que escribir los elementos de una lista ejemplo lista= [1,2,3,4,5] luego se tienen que eliminar el primer y ultimo elemento de la lista quedaría lista = [2,3,4] eso tiene que ir en la primera función se llama eliminar, luego tengo que crear otra función que se llame medio el cual tiene que eliminar el primer y ultimo elemento de nuevo de la lista entonces la lista quedaría lista = [3], pero no se como pasar la lista a la otra función.

Comment: Para pasar una lista solo envía el elemento a la función. 
Como te muestro el código que genere, defino una función que recibe una lista(puede tener cualquier nombre, en este caso lo llame lista), eso es lo que recibe el método medio(), entonces lo que haces en la función eliminar es enviar en el método medio(), la lista que estas manejando. 
Revisa de nuevo el código que lo voy a actualizar.

Comment: Gracias me funciono